# how to add multiple filters to mapbox leaflet maps

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, leaflet, mapbox

I have a working mapbox/leaflet map and I can filter based on dropdowns but only one of them will work, not sure of the syntax (or if it's possible) to combine filters?

I basically have a real estate map populated with json data which includes property types and neighborhoods. need to combine the possible filters, so selecting a different property type won't erase the neighborhood filter.

```
$('#propertytype').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'all') {
        console.log($(this).val());
        markers.setFilter(function(f) {
            return f.properties['type'] != null;
        });
    } else {
        console.log($(this).val());
        var ptype = $(this).val();
        markers.setFilter(function(f) {
            return f.properties['type'] === ptype;
        });
        return false;
    }
});

$('#neighborhood').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'all') {
        console.log($(this).val());
        markers.setFilter(function(f) {
            return f.properties['neighborhood'] != null;
        });
    } else {
        console.log($(this).val());
        var hood = $(this).val();
        markers.setFilter(function(f) {
            return f.properties['neighborhood'] === hood;
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, simplify into one function:

```
$('#propertytype, #neighborhood').change(function() {
    var propertyType = $('#propertytype').val();
    var neighborhood = $('#neighborhood').val();
    markers.setFilter(function(f) {
        return (propertyType === 'all' || f.properties.type == propertyType) &&
            (neighborhood === 'all' || f.properties.neighborhood === neighborhood);
    });
    return false;
});
```

(haven't executed this code, but should work)

Comment: perfect! this is what I was trying to do, but didn't know how it's done in javascript. thanks!